# How to change label location?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

How to change label location in Java Swing? I want to see coordinates where I clicked.   `jlb.SetLocation(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());` doesn't work.

```
public TestPanels() {

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            jlb.setText(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
        }
    });
add(jlb);
}
```

Comment: `jlb.SetLocation(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());`  Are you familiar with the term 'coding by magic'?  It means 'tossing random statements together in the (futile) hope that something works'..  It's what I think of when seeing that code snippet that would not even compile.

Comment: BTW - at fist I though you meant to **set the location of the label,** so I changed the text to suit.  But the original title/first sentence and the 2nd code snippet all indicate you simply want to **display the mouse location in the label** (much simpler).  Which is it?

Comment: Did you add the panel to the frame? Does your panel have a size? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

write `jlb.setLocation(x,y);`
and make sure you have a relative layout
to make your layout relative `write setLayout(null);`